# JavaScript object method name for setTimeout

Tags: javascript

my object has a function that i want to call recurseively.
my problem is how do i use setTimeout to point to the method of that instance of the object?

```
MyObject.prototype.Play = function() {

  // do some stuff
  setTimeout(thecurrentmethodnameHERE, 1000);
}

var test = new MyObject();

test.Play();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do `setTimeout(this.someMethod, 1000)`, but keep in mind that it will be called in a global context, so any reference to `this` inside `someMethod` will be `window`, assuming a web browser.

You can do it like this in your constructor, if that's an issue:

```
YourObject = function(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
  self.someMethod = function() {
    alert(self.name); // this.name would have been window.name
  };
  setTimeout(self.someMethod, 1000);
};
```

Some libraries define `Function.prototype.bind` which you can use in these situations, `setTimeout(this.someMethod.bind(this), 1000)`, which simply returns a new function that gets `call()`ed with your desired object as `this`, it's a nice, simple function that you can implement without messing with the `Function` prototype too.

Comment: freakin nlogax, what are you doin here!

Answer (score 0):

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
  var _function = this;

  return function() {
    return _function.apply(scope, arguments);
  }
}

MyObject.prototype.Play = function() {

  // do some stuff
  setTimeout(thecurrentmethodnameHERE.bind(this), 1000);
}
```